# What is the difference between ASP.NET MVC 5, ASP.NET Core MVC 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I know that .NET Core 3.1 is followed by .NET 5 (this is by itself .net core).

I also know that .NET 4.8 is the last windows only (non .net core) framework.

So I think that ASP.NET MVC 5, ASP.NET Core MVC 5 are both the same. Is that correct?

Comment: Not at all. ASP.NET MVC 5 runs on .net framework, which is essentially a discontinued product line. All new development should be on .net 5/6.

Comment: But isn't .NET 4.8 the final windows only (non .net core) framework?

Comment: .NET **Framework** 4.8 is the final windows-only framework, yes. You're missing the word _Framework_ there. See [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-5/). To reiterate what Tanveer said, .NET Framework is effectively discontinued, and .NET Core has become .NET 5, .NET 6, and so on.

Comment: What is confusing me is that - since you are saying that .NET core has become .NET 5, then why is .NET 5 MVC and .NET 5 Core MVC different?

Comment: I think you are talking about ASP.NET Core MVC and ASP.NET MVC 5. ASP.NET Core MVC uses .NET Core(1-3) as well as .NET(5/6) and  ASP.NET MVC 5 uses .NET Framework.

Comment: ASP.Net MVC 5 runs on .Net Framework 4.8 - ASP.Net Core 5 (which includes all the MVC and Web API bits) runs on .Net 5 which is the version after .Net Core 3 (there was no .Net Core 4)

Comment: `.NET 5 (this is by itself .net core)`...it's not _just_ .NET Core. .NET 5 amalgamated a number of disaparate .NET-related platforms together - see https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-5/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC

ASP.NET MVC 1.0 was released on 13 March 2009, not part of the .NET Framework, running on top of ASP.NET, which was then part of .NET Framework 3.5.

MVC's version did not correspond to .NET Framework/ASP.NET versioning. MVC went through version 2, 3 and 4 and ASP.NET MVC 5 was released on 17 October 2013. Meanwhile the .NET Framework went from 3.5 to 4.7, now 4.8 but will never reach a higher major version.

---

Then .NET Core started under the working title "vNext". It was .NET Core 1, then 2, then 3. .NET Core includes ASP.NET Core, which included ASP.NET Core MVC. This versioned along with its framework.

Now to prevent confusion, they didn't want to name the fourth version of .NET Core as 4, because that'd conflict (not on a filesystem level, but in the heads of developers) with .NET Framework 4. So they unified .NET Framework and .NET Core, and called it .NET 5.

---

.NET 5 includes ASP.NET Core 5, which includes ASP.NET Core MVC 5, which is *not* the same as ASP.NET MVC 5.

The old .NET Framework (currently 4.8) and ASP.NET MVC 5.2.7 are considered finished. Maybe they'll receive security patches, but you shouldn't do new development in it, and skip tutorials that mention it.

Comment: As ever, Microsoft has confused a lot of people with the naming and numbering of the .Net platform and ASP.Net.

Comment: @phuzi yeah they should've started with .NET Core 6 to prevent any confusion. Then we'd have questions like "Where is .NET Core 4.8?"... :P

Comment: Ok so effectively there are 2 ASP.NET MVC 5's - 1) .NET framework (ASP.NET MVC 5) and 2) .NET Core [aka .NET 5] (ASP.NET Core MVC 5)

Comment: @variable yes, there are two model-view-controller frameworks by Microsoft, (which can also be used for APIs and Razor pages), one framework is derived from the other, and they both have a version 5.

Comment: I get it now, I got mixed up with the number 5 (.NET 5 and MVC 5)

Comment: No, not exactly. There is no ASP.Net Core MVC 5! It's just ASP.NET Core 5 (there is no MVC in the name, it just includes MVC and Web API and Razor Pages and all the other ASP.Net stuff)

Comment: @phuzi well... There's the docs that call it "ASP.NET Core MVC" everywhere (https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/aspnet/core/?view=aspnetcore-6.0), there's the GitHub repository (https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/main/src/Mvc) that calls it "ASP.NET Core MVC", there are namespaces, and so on. The MVC component of the ASP.NET Core version that ships with .NET 5 can therefore be called "ASP.NET Core MVC 5", right?

Comment: @CodeCaster But the product is not called ASP.NET Core MVC. It's just ASP.Net Core with which you can build an MVC application. So building an ASP.Net Core MVC application is the same as saying building an MVC application with ASP.Net Core. It's a really subtle distinction and really confusing

Comment: @phuzi true. So you mean people shouldn't be using "ASP.NET Core MVC $version" anymore, but call it what, ".NET Core $version, ASP.NET (MVC)"? Not sure what I should change about my answer.

Comment: It would really help if it could be "ASP.Net Core $verison MVC" although this doesn't help when you're not discussing a specific version.

Comment: @variable At the risk of confusing you further, ASP.NET Core could be run on .net framework for a time being. That stopped being true around .net 3.0 timeline I believe.

Answer (score 0):

- There are several difference between ASP.NET Core 5 and ASP.NET MVC 5 in the solution structure. The ASP.NET Core is a composable framework for implementing web and cloud based applications.
- ASP .NET MVC 5 helps to choose the MVC or Web API and we can able to choose both while creating a web application. But in Core we can able to choose single-aligned web stack for MVC nad Web API.
- The file structure are varies between them. the ASP.NET MVC 5 concicts of web.config, Global.asax files. But the Core does not contain these files instead it contains appsettings.json.
- And the ASP .NET Core does not need IIS for hosting since it is to be cross-platform and it is self hosted.
- In ASP.NET Core applications, dependency injection is inbuilt and no set up is needed for DI. But in ASP.NET MVC we want to use saparate DI container and then build up the project to use DI.